# Yii2: how to make bootstrap tab active if there is any yii2 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii2

I have create a `CRUD` using `Yii2`.
Now i have added `multi-tab` using `bootstrap` 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-examples

Now i have some validation rule on field like `required validation`.
when save button is click then it shows error on active tab but if there is any error on inactive tab then it will not submit the form.
if there is any error in active tab user will correct them by doing proper action, but he will not understand that there is any error on other tabs as well.

So what i want if there is any error in other tab then that tab will become active.

and if user remove all validation error at active tab then try to re-submit the form then it will again move to next error containing tab.

here is my code of form

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <div class="nav-tabs-horizontal">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-line" data-plugin="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active" role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#user" arria-controls="user" role="tab">User Details</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#company" aria-controls="company" role="tab">Company Details</a></li>
    </ul>

 <div class="tab-content">

     <div class="tab-pane active" id="user" role="tabpanel">
         <div class="form-group form-material">`  
            <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'First Name']); ?>
            </div>
              <div class="form-group form-material">
              <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Last Name']); ?>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group form-material">
                <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->input('email'); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-material">
               <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['placeholder'=>'Password']);?> 
                </div>
                  <div class="form-group form-material">
                 <?= $form->field($model, 'repeatpassword')->passwordInput(['placeholder'=>'Repeat Password']);?>
                </div> 

      </div>

      <div class="tab-pane" id="company" role="tabpanel">

       <div class="form-group form-material">
        <?= $form->field($company, 'Title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>
        </div>

             <div class="form-group form-material">
            <?= $form->field($company, 'Website')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>
             </div>


              <div class="form-group form-material">
                  <?= $form->field($company, 'Description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]); ?>
               </div>

                <div class="form-group form-material">
                <?= $form->field($company, 'Status')->dropDownList(['Active' =>'Active','Deactive'=>'Deactive','Pending'=>'Pending'],['prompt'=>'']) ?>
                  </div>
          </div>
     </div>

      <?= Html::submitButton("Save", ["class" => "btn btn-success"]); ?>
   </div>
   <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

**1. Don't use tabs**

To put it bluntly, the idea of using tabs in a form which needs validation is generally regarded as a poor choice in terms of usability, because you are adding complexity to an already complex job: `validation`.
I'm not necessarily talking about the complexity of the programming logic, which might get high enough depending on your form, but about the complexity which comes from having to deal with (and focus the attention of) users who are having trouble with the form in the first place, who are typically the *"not so technically savvy"* ones.

A simple fix would be to put all your form into one scrollable container.

**2. Validate each tab separately, before leaving it**

This would probably be the best way to go. Just validate the current tab for elements on `show.bs.tab` event and `preventdefault()` if validation fails, showing the errors, (eventually) scrolling the tab to the first one.

If you go this route, you will need to divide your validation into separate functions, one for each tab. The overall validation of the form will be the sum of the individual tab validation functions. This will  make it simpler for your user to understand the form and go through it and  will probably increase the overall usability and success rate of your form.

The only *"tricky"* part of this would be to make sure the error is always scrolled into view, in case your tab contents don't fit into one screen. If you don't do this, it's possible that users try to change the tab and not understand why it's not working, making the form seem broken.

**3. Create a *"display first error"*** function

The last option is to make your validation function find and activate the tab of the first error. Not optimal, because it's harder to give the user info on how many errors are in total and how far he is from being able to actually submit the form, but it's better than trying to submit and not knowing why it's not working.

Depending on the actual markup of your form, this might be different but, in principle, if the selector for your error containing form element is  `.x`, this should make its tab active:
`$('.x').closest('[role="tabpanel"]').tab('show');`

Just like with option **2.**, you need to take extra care to scroll the error into view if it is not visible by default when the tab is activated.

Comment: Thank you @Andrei Gheorghiu for your reply. I appreciate Your answers. But the above code is only snip of my whole code. I have large number of fields so i can not go with single scrollable part. I have attach an image that is output of my form. 
please check that and suggest an better option.
i am using Yii2 validation rules so i dont want to write my own js rules for validation until it not the last option. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

As Andrei wrote in his answer, the best solution is to validate each tab separately before leaving it. This is the best way to handle it, as seen over the years.

Answer (score 0):

You should register JS file for your view like this

```
$this->registerJsFile('js/report/index.js', ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
```

and in this file add afterValidate() handler (substitute #report-index by your form id):

```
$('#report-index').on('afterValidate', function(event, messages, errorAttributes){
  if(errorAttributes.length > 0) {
    var errElement = $('#' + errorAttributes[0].id);
    var pane = errElement.closest('[class="tab-pane"]');
    var tabId = pane[0].id;
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tabId + '"]').tab('show');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you for your replay , even its very late but really appreciated. I will test this and let you know if its working. Thank You

Comment: @FahadAli, I was being stuck with the same problem, and after I eventually was able to resolve it with the help of this topic I decided to share my solution.